# Symfony3.2 upload a file

Tags: php, image, symfony, file-upload

i'm trying to upload a picture but i don't know why i always got  this error message.

> Error: Call to a member function guessExtension() on a non-object

this means that the object i got is null, but why?

this is my input`<input type="file" id="images_emp" name="images_emp"  >`.
now in the contrller i did this:

```
$pic = $request->files->get('images_emp');
$imagenom=$nom.$Cin.'.'.$pic->guessExtension();
$pic->move( $this->getParameter('Dossier_images'),imagenom);
$Employe->setImgsrc("/images/".$imagenom);
```

and in this is what the entity looks like.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "1024k",
 *     mimeTypes={ "application/png" ,"application/jpg","application/jpeg"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Svp inserer une forme valide (png,jpg,jpeg)"
 *     )
 */private $imgsrc;

  /**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getImgsrc()
{
    return $this->imgsrc;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $imgsrc
 */
public function setImgsrc($imgsrc)
{
    $this->imgsrc = $imgsrc;
    return $this;
}
```

how could i solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i advice you to use the events in entity is very simple and good then get()

> Entity  Images

```
    <?php
namespace  ------------ ;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Images
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="images")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="---------")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Slides
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url;


    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $alt;

    private $file;

    //This attribute is added to store the temporary file name
    private $tempFilename;


    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     *
     * @return Images
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }


    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }


    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        // We check if we already had a file for this entity
        if (null !== $this->url) {
            // The file extension is saved to be deleted later
            $this->tempFilename = $this->url;

            // Reset the values of the url and alt attributes
            $this->url = null;
            $this->alt = null;
        }    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        // If there is no file (optional field), nothing is done
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // The name of the file is its id, you just have to store its extension
        // To make it clean, we should rename this attribute to "extension" instead of "url"
        $this->url = $this->file->guessExtension();

        // And we generate the alt attribute of the <img> tag, at the file name value on the user's PC
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        //If there is no file (optional field), nothing is done
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        //If we had an old file, we delete it
        if (null !== $this->tempFilename) {
            $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->tempFilename;
            if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
                unlink($oldFile);
            }
        }

        // We move the file sent in the directory of your choice
        $this->file->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(), // Le répertoire de destination
            $this->id.'.'.$this->url   // Le nom du fichier à créer, ici « id.extension »
        );
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function preRemoveUpload()
    {
        // We temporarily save the file name because it depends on the id
        $this->tempFilename = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->url;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        // In PostRemove, we do not have access to the id, we use our saved name
        if (file_exists($this->tempFilename)) {
            // we delete the file
            unlink($this->tempFilename);
        }
    }

    public function getUploadDir()
    {
        // Returns the relative path to the image for a browser
         return 'uploads';
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // We return the relative path to the image for our PHP code
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getId().'.'.$this->getUrl();
    }



    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $alt
     *
     * @return Images
     */
    public function setAlt($alt)
    {
        $this->alt = $alt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get alt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAlt()
    {
        return $this->alt
    }
}
```

> In controller

```
$images = new Images();
$form   = $this->get('form.factory')->create(ImagesType::class, $images);
if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($images);
    $em->flush();
}
```

and you can find this solution in [openclassroom](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony/creer-des-formulaires-avec-symfony#/id/r-3777443) more more detailed